# Template file naming with alias

Tags: theming

I have a few template node overrides in my theme using Drupal 7.

For example: page--node--53.tpl.php

This might be a lazy request, but is there anyway to name these files instead with the alias I have chosen rather then using the node number? That way I don't have to memorize all of the associated pages.

For example page--node--about.tpl.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this in template.php should do the trick:

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
    $alias = drupal_get_path_alias("node/$node->nid");

    // Remove slashes from the potential filename
    $clean_alias = str_replace('/', '__', $alias);

    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__node__' . $clean_alias;
  }
}
```

You might need to massage your `$clean_alias` variable a bit more to handle any punctuation you're allowing into aliases (e.g. with Pathauto).

A node with an alias like `about/about-us` would then use a template file called `page--node--about--about-us.tpl.php`.

Comment: this worked great for me as well.  just made one change because hyphen weren't working for me in the name (e.g. about-us):     $clean_alias = str_replace('-', '_', str_replace('/', '__', $alias));

Answer (score 3):

In THEMENAME_preprocess_page (in template.php located in your themes directory) you can set as many template hook suggestions as you wish. Drupal then goes through the list from bottom to top and once it finds the existing template suggestion, it stops and uses that one.

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  // Add theme hook suggestions based on path for nodes only.
  if (isset($vars['node'])) {
    // get whatever you want here into $path variable
    $path = $vars['node']['type'];
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__node__' . $path;
  }
}
```

in the $vars there should be the node object that you can check for
$vars['node']. also don't forget to sanitize anything you are adding there. good choice would be to use the [drupal_clean_css_identifier](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_clean_css_identifier/7) function

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [this thread](http://groups.drupal.org/node/130944#comment-425189) in which someone has implemented this kind of template suggestions.