# Drupal 8 page template for view page

Tags: views, theming, 8

I know it should be very simple, I know it was working in Drupal 7 but I can't make it work in 8.

I tried [this](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/twig-template-naming-conventions) but it is not working. "page--path.html.twig" is not used, Drupal is using the "page.html.twig" template. The page I'm trying to theme is "example.com/path" . This page is just a view page. I'm not interested in theming the view, just the page markup around it.

Comment: If 'path' is an alias it won't work.

Comment: yeah, found the problem. It was an alias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since its an alias,

For Drupal 8

In your THEME_NAME.theme file:

```
function THEME_NAME_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  // Checks for node pages. 
  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
    $alias = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getAliasByPath($current_path);
    $alias = ltrim('/', $alias);
    $clean_alias = str_replace('/', '__', $alias);
    $suggestions[] = 'page__'.$clean_alias;
  }
}
```

You would like to check out clive answer from here for drupal 7

[Template file naming with alias](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52408/template-file-naming-with-alias)

Comment: Hi, shouldn't the hook's name be "THEME_NAME_*theme*_suggestions_page_alter"?

Comment: updated yes it should be hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter